# How do I make my player face the direction the camera is moving in Godot 4?

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

I have this player script in Godot 4:

```
extends CharacterBody3D

@onready var pivot_y = $CamOriginY
@onready var pivot_x = $CamOriginY/CamOriginX
@onready var springarm = $CamOriginY/CamOriginX/SpringArm3D

const SPEED = 5.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = 4.5


@export var is_moving = false
@export var forward_angle = ""
@export var facing_dir = ""
@export var sens: float = 0.5
@export var zoom_speed: float = 14.0
@export var spring_length_default: float = 1.0
@export var spring_length_min: float = 0.0
@export var spring_length_max: float = 2.0
@export var spring_length_target = spring_length_default
@export var spring_length_current = spring_length_default

var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")

func _ready():
    Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED

func _input(event):
    
    
    if is_moving == true:
        if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
            
            pivot_x.rotate_x(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.y * sens))
            rotate_y(deg_to_rad(pivot_y.rotation.y * -event.relative.x * sens))
            
            pivot_x.rotation.x = clamp(pivot_x.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-30), deg_to_rad(45))
    else:
        if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
            pivot_x.rotate_x(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.y * sens))
            pivot_y.rotate_y(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.x * sens))
            
            pivot_x.rotation.x = clamp(pivot_x.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-30), deg_to_rad(45))
            
    if event.is_action_pressed("cam_zoom_in"):
        if spring_length_current > spring_length_min:
            spring_length_target = spring_length_current - 0.4
        else:
            print("At minimum value")
    elif event.is_action_pressed("cam_zoom_out"):
        if spring_length_current < spring_length_max:
            spring_length_target = spring_length_current + 0.4
        else:
            print("At maximum value")

    if event.is_action_pressed("left"):
        facing_dir = "left"
    elif event.is_action_pressed("right"):
        facing_dir = "right"
    elif event.is_action_pressed("up"):
        print("hello")
    elif event.is_action_pressed("down"):
        facing_dir = "down"

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    is_moving = false
    
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta

    # Handle jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("quit"):
        get_tree().quit()

    spring_length_current = lerp(spring_length_current, float(spring_length_target), delta * zoom_speed)
    springarm.set_length(spring_length_current)

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "up", "down")
    var direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y))
    if direction:
        is_moving = true
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)


    move_and_slide()
```

In this script the camera is controlled by two nodes, one node (`pivot_x`) only rotates on the x axis and `pivot_y` only the y (to prevent Gimbol lock).

When the player doesn't move the camera can rotate around the player in an orbit state without affecting the player's direction.

However when the player then moves, it moves continuing in the direction it was facing. I would like it so if the camera orbits around the player, then the player rotates to face the direction the `pivot_y` y axis is facing so that will then be the new forward. I do not know Godot well enough to program it so I came here :).

I was thinking that maybe something could be called in the `is moving = true` part of the script to rotate it to the camera. However I didn't know how to make it so that it would only call once and not affect the `rotate_y(deg_to_rad(pivot_y.rotation.y * -event.relative.x * sens))` part. Pls help

I've tried the look_at function to make the player look at `pivot_y` but then the player just looked at the floor. I've tried messing around in the direction code to see if I could get the way it is programmed to change.

Answer (score -1):

you are using the wrong axis, forward is -x

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: no my answer is corrent and it's clear .... the "camera" is facing the wrong way because it is facing the x axis, he needs to orient the camera to -x.